# Implicit numeric widening in Scala 2.10, but not 2.11 or 2.12

Tags: scala

I'm running in a very odd scalac behaviour. This is the code I'm trying to compile:

```
case class A(a: Char, b: Char)
```

For some reason, when enabling the `-Ywarn-numeric-widen` flag (which I do for all my projects, as well as `-Xfatal-warnings`):

- 2.10.6 will warn `implicit numeric widening`
- 2.11.8 and 2.12.1 are fine

I'm not sure where the warning comes from, nor how to work around it. I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't involve dropping support for 2.10 or force me to "weaken" my compilation process...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's a known scalac bug - supposed to have been fixed, but apparently not well enough: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8340

Comment: The page says it's fixed in Scala 2.11.0, which fits what you see.

Comment: Right - since it was fixed before 2.10.4, I assumed it had been backported, but you're absolutely right: it specifically says it's not fixed before 2.11.

Comment: 2.10 is looking old now, but it's too bad -Xreporter isn't available there as a backstop.